# regarding email with attachment in php

Tags: php, email, attachment, encode

Can any one hel me?? I am trying to send an email with attachment it sends the email but the email is send in encoded format I think the problem is with headers can any one give me the working code.. there are lots of ready made code available on net i tried all of them but none of them is working

Comment: Try using some good library like phpmailer ...

Comment: Put some code , if you need us to find a solution for this ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use  PHPMailer  http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

Dowload Link : http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/downloads/detail?name=PHPMailer_5.2.1.zip&can=2&q=

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //defaults to using php "mail()"; the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

try {
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
  $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
  $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // attachment
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif'); // attachment
  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK</p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

Thanks

:)