# MySQL daily backups with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I am using Cpanel2 on my webhost, and it has full backup option, but that's not what I need.

I am thinking of some way to make my application make daily backup of database and e-mail me file.

I think I could do that with one PHP page, to do it with login or with running it, but It's not safe and it's similar to Cpanel backup itself.

Is there any way to make my phpmyadmin or cpanel to send me backup of database on mail ?

EDIT: I have tried with `system("mysqldump -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname > $backupfile");` But all I get is 0KB empty file.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

1)

```
    <?php
$db_file_name = $_GET['file_name'];
backup_tables($_GET['host'],$_GET['user'],$_GET['pass'],$_GET['database']);

/* backup the db OR just a table */
function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')
{
    global $db_file_name;
  $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  mysql_select_db($name,$link);

  //get all of the tables
  if($tables == '*')
  {
    $tables = array();
    $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
      $tables[] = $row[0];
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
  }

  //cycle through
  foreach($tables as $table)
  {
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

    $return.= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$table.';';
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
    $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
    {
      while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
      {
        $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
        for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
        {
          $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
          $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
          if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
          if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
        }
        $return.= ");\n";
      }
    }
    $return.="\n\n\n";
  }  
  //save file
  $handle = fopen($db_file_name.'.sql','w+');
  fwrite($handle,$return);
  fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

This will save an .sql file in whatever folder you run this from. Then just do a simple php-mailer with this attached, and off you go.

2) I've been using syncsage.com for this and website backups. It's still in beta but so far it's amazing.

Comment: I like 1st one more, and this was my 1st idea, but in that case I have to manually run file every hour/day, and I need to make it do automatically in midnight. That's hard part for me

Comment: Easy peasy! Throw that script on your server, set up a cron job to run at midnight, and it'll run and email you.

Comment: Heres a great post about php and emailing attachments:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926808/regarding-email-with-attachment-in-php

Comment: Hmmm, gotta check up then what's Cron Job and how to do it aswell.

Comment: If your using a control panel of some sort, them make it really easy. Are you using cPanel or plesk or anything? It's usually under Schedule Tasks, or even simply Cron Jobs.

Comment: I have Cpanel2 on webhost. Will look under it now, but this code you provided is not working. Since ereg_replace is not working on php 5.3

Comment: use preg_replace for 5.3 or higher.

Comment: Tried to replace it, but not working... it says that preg_replace has some other parms.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your database, your host may not support sending such a big file. What you need to do is create a cron job (with PHP) or a schedule job in phpMyAdmin that will create a dump of your database. You would then need a script that sends this backup to you.

Comment: Hello, this is also my problem right now. About the CRON job and phpMyAdmin, can you lead me on how to get started on this? Perhaps a link to a tutorial? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @xjshiya you can just search this site for the terms `mysql cron`